# Doorbell won't stop ringing

Tags: doorbell

The other day I was on my front porch painting my shutters and I was painting the one next to my Ring doorbell. After about 10 minutes of standing in front the Ring, my doorbell began ringing over and over. I disconnect one of the wires from the doorbell inside my house. Why doe this happening?

Comment: Disconnect and remove the Ring doorbell unit entirely, including the jumper diode that I believe is required when installing on a regular low volt ac doorbell system. Reconnect the bell inside the house, then take the two wires where the Ring was connected and briefly touch them together, then apart. If the bell/chime acts normally, then the problem is with your Ring unit.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it answers go down there vvv